# Multiple Dictionaries into List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}
]
```

thats my data, I can't get this to work:

```
for i in data:
       c= [(k,v) for k,v in data[i].items()]
       c.sort()
       print(c)
```

I need to iterate through a list of dictionaries. After i got the List I need to get the "v's" into a new List.

Thanks in advance!

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

thats how the lists should look like

Comment: Please explain why the current code fails.

Comment: `data[i].items()` => `i.items()`

Comment: thanks!! love that forum

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid I don't understand the logic. Where did the second dict go? I guess the problem is that you assumed `i` was an index when it was really a dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` in `for i in data` is the dict itself so use:

```py
data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}
]

for i in data:
       c= [(k,v) for k, v in i.items()]
       c.sort()
       print(c)
```

Comment: Ohhh yeah... Thanks man! Probably should go to sleep soon haha

Comment: @Orsons Please consider accepting the answer if it helps you.

Comment: how do I "accept" the answer? Can't upvote because not enough reputation